# Video will not autoplay when clicked

Tags: html, html5-video, fancybox-2, video.js

For some reason, my videos do not autoplay when clicked. I have set my video element as:

```
<video id="epsilon_launch" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" data-setup="{}" width="920" height="518" controls autoplay>
<source src="video/epsilon_launch.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It autoplays correctly when using IE8 (.swf fallback for non-HTML5 browsers). [Live link here](http://ogmda.com/3dms-public/gallery.php).

Comment: Check out this post -- might shed some light:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184677/html5-video-with-fancybox

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Unfortunately, I do not know how to implement that workaround in my code.

Comment: Does it work if you use `data-setup='{"autoplay":true}'` instead of `autoplay`?

Comment: Looks like it does not:(

Comment: Guys, it works at my office computers, but does not work on the computers here at home. Either way, that's what matters.

Comment: Does autoplay work if you just use a raw video element? As @b.kelley said in his comment, this is a really old version of VJS, and on top of that there seems to be a lot of weirdness going on around your stylesheets.

Comment: That being said, pretty sure @pedro answered your question with his comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("epsilon_launch"); 
 myVideo.play(); 
</script>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

heres how I would do it.

```
$("a#videolink").fancybox({
    frameWidth: 920,
    frameHeight: 518,
    padding: 0,
    scrolling: 'no',
    afterShow: function() { _V_(this.href.replace('#','')).play() }
});
```

In `this.href` this is a reference to the link, so grabbing the href attribute and removing the `#` gives you the id for the video.  Using this, you can use the *V* method to grab a reference to the player and tell it to play.

FYI: you're using a rather old version of video.js